# VS2010 extension, lost it and can't remember name

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, vsx

Does anyone use or rememebr the name of the VS2010 extension that add a little faded context sensitive icon next to a class/ method (indiciating if it's a class etc like in the Class View) and adds a little faded clickable link at the end of a class/method block etc with it's name?

It looked someting like:

> [ICON] methodName1(params)
>   {
>    lines of code
>    more lines
>    line
>   } >> methodName1 (faded clickable link)

Lost it and can't find it and it's driving me nuts (too tired?)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I finally found it (not sure how it escaped me seeing as how it's from the author of the most excellent CodeMap / AxTools)

**VS10x Editor View Enhancer**

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/34eee02b-f1f6-433a-b210-62e94c0bcb87?SRC=VSIDE

[image: VS10x Editor View Enhancer]

Comment: Does anyone know how to Uninstall VS10x? I personally do not like it. It is not under Programs & Features.

Comment: These are VS2010 Extensions and can be managed (uninstalled/disabled etc) from VS2010 main menu: Tools->Extension Manager

Answer (score 0):

Are you thinking of [CodeRush](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/Visual_Studio_Add-in/Coding_Assistance/)

[image]

Comment: Thanks but no, I relaized my initial post was a bit fuyzzy, clarified it a bit.